# Integral on space

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the integral of the following function :

$$\displaystyle f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2}}\tag{f}$$

over the region bounded by $z=0$ two sphere's with radii $1,2$ and outside the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

**My attempt**: By writing this integral in spherical coordinate and using fubini theorem I got to :

$$\displaystyle\int\limits_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\,\int\limits_{\rho=1}^{2}\,\int\limits_{\varphi=\frac{\pi}{4}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\rho^2\sin{\varphi}}{\sqrt{\rho^2-4\rho\cos{\varphi}+4}}\,\mathrm d{\varphi}\,\mathrm d\rho \,\mathrm d\theta\tag{I}$$

WRT to $\varphi$ we can easily compute the integral which leads to :

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_{1}^{2}\rho/2\sqrt{\rho^2+4}-\sqrt{\rho^2-2\sqrt{2}\rho+4}\,\mathrm d\rho \,\mathrm d\theta$$

But WRT to $\rho$ it becomes a nightmare integral.It is computable but the result is too complicated and long to achive(A lot of substituations is needed)Is there any easier way so that I am overcomplicating things?Since It is an exam problem I don't think this will be the intended solution and there should be one with less calculations.Thanks in advance!

Edit:Spheres are centered at origin.

Comment: You did not specify the spheres appropriately. Where are their centres?

Comment: @VIVID They are centered at origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set it up in cylindrical coordinates,

Cone: $C1: r = z, z \geq 0$, Spheres: $S1: r^2+z^2 = 1, S2: r^2+z^2 = 4$

At intersection of cone and spheres,

$C1, S1: r = z = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}; \  C1, S2: r = z = \sqrt2$

The region is $R: r \geq z \geq 0,\  1 \leq r^2 + z^2 \leq 4$

So integral is,

$\displaystyle I = \small 2\pi \int_0^{1 / \sqrt2} \int_{\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + (z-2)^2}} \ dr \ dz \ + 2\pi \int_{1 / \sqrt2}^{\sqrt2} \int_{z}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + (z-2)^2}} \ dr \ dz$

As $ \displaystyle \small \int \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + (z-2)^2}} \ dr = \sqrt{r^2+(z-2)^2} + C$,

$I =  \displaystyle \small 2\pi \int_0^{1 / \sqrt2} \left[2\sqrt{2-z} - \sqrt{5-4z} \right] \ dz \ + 2\pi \int_{1 / \sqrt2}^{\sqrt2} \left[2\sqrt{2-z} - \sqrt2  \sqrt{(z-1)^2+1}\right] \ dz$

$=  \displaystyle \small 4\pi \int_0^{\sqrt2} \sqrt{2-z} \ dz - 2 \pi \int_0^{1 / \sqrt2} \sqrt{5-4z} \ dz \ - 2 \sqrt2 \pi \int_{1 / \sqrt2}^{\sqrt2} \sqrt{(z-1)^2+1} \ dz$

And they are all standard integrals. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Nice!Can you provide any motivation for using cylindrical coordinate?I used spherical because we had two spheres.But cylindrical coordinate use is a bit odd to me.

Comment: Yes you are right that if we go by the region, spherical coordinates would be the natural choice. But when we look at the function we need to integrate, it is not symmetric to z-plane. So one of the ways is to use spherical coordinates but use change of variable to $z = 2 + \rho \cos \phi$ but that would make the bounds somewhat complicated. Now my motivation to use cylindrical coordinates - given the function is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + (z-2)^2}}$ and there is jacobian $r$ in the numerator in cylindrical coordinates, it should turn out an easy integral wrt $dr$.